# Read text file in Javascript Rhino

Tags: javascript, rhino

I am writing a code to read a local text file into my No Magic Cameo Systems Modeler. I am using Javascript Rhino for the same. But not getting any viable solution to read the text file.

[image]

I used Java's bufferedReader class but then I am getting the following error :

**"org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (#25)"**

Can anyone assist me in what I am doing wrong. I am fairly new to javascript .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to execute Java code, not JavaScript code, so Rhino throws an error because you're not providing it valid JavaScript code

For example `File fileR = ...`: this is Java code. The JavaScript equivalent is: `var fileR = ....`

Comment: Can you also assist me in one more thing . My text file contains only path to different files. for e.g. :                                                                                                                                                "C:\\Users\\hu170f\\Documents\\IncomingSupcoSim\\IncomingSupcoSim\\Enterprise system\\LN1\\MAAP-S12_LH_LOW_PASS-LN1-V1-C1.csv"
I want to read the contents of this text file  such that I can extract the paths one by one in loop .

Comment: I think there are enough online resources on how to read Files line by line in Java, like https://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java